# Absolute positioning if content above an item is changing (bottom vs top vs other?)

Tags: html, css

I am currently working within a platform that is pretty restrictive. I can't add classes and can't add Javascript. Yes, it sucks.

I have created a button and placed it next to a few other buttons (by giving it absolute positioning) but the issue is when a user adds a guest to a registration, it totally throws off the positioning of the element due to the additional information coming in above it.

I thought by using the CSS - "bottom" property I would be able to position the element in such a way that it would always stay in line with the "real" buttons.

Is there such a way to do this using strictly CSS? Here is my code:

```
.footerbackbutton {
height: 20px;
width: 77px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 360px;
bottom: 17% !important;
padding-right: 32px !important;
}
```

FYI: I have tried using pixels instead of percentages. They both seem to fail.

Comment: The code you posted seems to me to do roughly what you're asking. If you create a mockup in JSFiddle, then it may be easier for us to see how it isn't working!

Comment: It works, the issue is that paddings and margins are changing as a user adds a guest. So in the initial registration, where it is one user, the position is correct. But on the page after the user adds a guest, the positioning changes and the "button" is moved down a certain amount of pixels. The issue is, this is all happening on the same "page" in the platform.

Comment: It may have something to do with your other css classes. Depending on how your HTML wraps the footer or not. It may be that your absolute position is absolute compared to something else (like the bottom of the header) instead of an absolute position on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I put the fake button in my footer. By moving the div to an editable HTML section in the top of the page and adding inline styles I was able to successfully adjust to information being added below that div. The bottom remains the same on both of those pages.